# NSXMLParserDelegate warning

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsxmlparser

After adding `@interface MedicalRecordViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,NSXMLParserDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>` my appilcation still shows the warning in the

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
XmlParser *parser = [[XmlParser alloc] initXMLParser];
if (serviceRequest==1) {
    [parser setPageRequest:2];
}else if (serviceRequest==2) {
    [parser setPageRequest:5];
}else if (serviceRequest==3) {
    [parser setPageRequest:4];
}else if (serviceRequest==4) {
    [parser setPageRequest:4];
}
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser]; // warning here
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
```

warning message

```
Sending 'XmlParser *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSXMLParserDelegate>'
```

Whats wrong in my code?Should i want to add any other things?

Comment: i think warning should be in this line : [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

Comment: Yes, Sorry,I will update the questNow.

Comment: @H2CO3 has already edited your question and yes XmlParser class doesn't implement the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol as he mentioned.

Comment: @Suny Yeah. Is there any alternatives to correc the warning

Comment: if you have the permission (source code), you can edit it to implement the "NSXMLParserDelegate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XmlParser` class doesn't implement the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Then how to remove that warning

Comment: @fazil Not sure what are you actually trying to do, but you should make the delegate the object of which the class conforms to this protocol.